# c++ -fpermissive error while implement callback in c++

Tags: c++

```
    class Caller{
private:
    CallBackInterface &m_cb;
public:
    Caller(CallBackInterface& cb):m_cb(cb){};
```

doesn't give -fpermissive error whereas following gives. Why is it so?

```
class Caller{
private:
    CallBackInterface &m_cb;
public:
    Caller(CallBackInterface& cb){
        m_cb=cb;
    };
```

Comment: Note that these mean different things. The first makes `m_cb` refer to the same object as `cb`, the second assigns a new value to the object that `m_cb` refers to (i.e. an non-existent object, if you would allow it),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reference variable should be initialized when declaring. As a member variable is constructed in a constructor, so it should be in the initialization list .

If you are trying to initialize a member reference variable inside a constructor, it would be an assignment as the variable should have already been defined.

So your code has issues in two fold

1. Reference variable is not initialized when defined
2. Reference variable is assigned once it has been defined inside the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat simplified, but construction of the member variables is done before the body of your constructor is executed, and references needs to be initialized at construction (because you can't have a reference that doesn't reference anything) so you need to do it in the constructors initializer list.